# Where are all the nodes in openstack needed for?

Tags: openstack, cloud

I am currently learning Openstack (which is harder than I thought it would be). I see that when using Ubuntu and autopilot the install needs at least 6 nodes (excluding the managing node, correct me I am wrong here).

But what are all these nodes for? I looked at the internet, but am not exactly sure. Mostly because some posts are old or very short? I could guess for the compute node the network node and the storage node, but what else?

Answer (score 0):

You only need 5 physical machines to use autopilot.  The services are distributed during the installation but in my deployment, it's like this.

1. MAAS
2. Landscape
3. Node01 - Nuetron
4. Node02 - Compute
5. Node03 - Compute

I believe using autopilot there are 12 virtual machines configured and placed on the physical servers.  I don't know if it's standardize with autopilot.  To me, it appears as though I have 2 usable compute nodes to launch instances on.